# Js and css files not loading from bundle.cs after upgrading umbraco (return 404)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, http-status-code-404, bundle, umbraco, umbraco7

we upgraded our umbrao from 7.10.0V to 7.12.4V.
after installation we have noticed that all js & css files which suppose load from bundle.cs return 404 status.
why is that happened?
thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

after searching for an answer we've noticed that global.asax not fired at all!.
seeing the history of the file showed that

```
<%@ Application Codebehind="Global.asax.cs" Inherits="**" Language="C#" %>
```

line was overridden after the upgrade.

changing this code back to what it was fixed the problem :).

Answer (score 0):

Have yoou checked namespace of Global.asax? Maybe still novice to umbraco.
Needed: Umbraco.Global instead of: Umbraco.Web.UmbracoApplication